# How to apply reinforcement learning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I understand it in concept. You have an agent and an environment. And then you have a set of states, which each have a value. The agent then either choses to "explore" or "exploit" and modifies it's knowledge according to what happened.

My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to actually apply it to code or to any actual problem. Everytime I look it up, I just end up getting the same few equations with no explanation on how to use them.

I'm trying to write a RL agent for tetris, and I can't seem to figure it out. It'd be great if someone could ELI5.

How do I know what to put as a state? What about actions? What's the actual math involved for adjusting the values? It's all so confusing.

If someone could help me out, i'd really appreciate it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Reinforcement learning is used in situations, where you don't know the correct answer, but given an answer can easily tell whether it is correct or not.

Find a problem with a limited or smooth continuous state space, like helicopter control. In this particular example, you could use a simplified physics simulation to teach an agent how to perform the task without needing to imbue it with explicit rules.

If you google for applications of Reinforcement Learning to tetris, you will find much has been written on the subject.

To understand what constitutes states, actions, etc, read Sutton and Barton's "Reinforcement Learning." You can find it freely available online.